# Difference between loadUrl and loadData with javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I try to load in an Android webview a html page with an ajax post request.

When I load the webview with loadUrl, the javascript works fine, but when I try to load with loadData (I need it) I get an error : "`NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101`". This error sounds like a access control origin problem.

The parseJsoup function replace some string in the html page with good strings. I check the data that I pass to loadData and the script part is not alterate.

My oncreate function :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        
    String html = parseJsoup("index.html");

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    //myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");            
    myBrowser.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
}
```

And my javascript code :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  datatype: "json",
  async: false,
});


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my url",
    data: 'my data',        
    success: function(data){
    // Do some action here with the data variable that contains the resulting message
      document.write("OK "+JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
      document.write("KO "+JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean, `android.webkit.WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL` when you say loadData, and `android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl` when you say loadUrl.

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary.html), only difference between them is, loadURL renders a webkit having a url that you set. On the other hand, loadData renders webkit, that source code comes from a parameter, and baseURL is also a parameter.

The javascript error message you get, is mostly related to when you attempt a cross domain ajax request. This seems more plausable for your case since the only difference between your methods seems to be one of them is an actual URL other one is dynamically created webpage, having no solid url.

And also from [documentation of loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> "... The base URL is used both to resolve relative URLs and when applying
>   JavaScript's same origin policy."

And your not setting baseURL parameter might give us clue about the issue.

Try assigning some dummy domain name or a domain you own to baseURL and also append this domain to your javascript ajax resource endpoint. Such as:

```
myBrowser.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://mydomain/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

and on Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://mydomain/my url",
    data: 'my data',        
    success: function(data){
    // Do some action here with the data variable that contains the resulting message
      document.write("OK "+JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
      document.write("KO "+JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```